# Why does Kilmandaros hate the Eleint?

Tags: malazan

I am currently on Dust of Dreams (book 9 of Malazan) and I have to ask why exactly does Kilmandaros hate the Eleint so much? I know bits of her back story as an Elder Goddess and the only time it coincides with Eleint is when she decides to start "driving the pretenders out of Shadow" (when her and Rake are together in Shadow). Is there a reason for her anger?

Comment: The gods are idiots so i don't think she needs more reason than "pretenders showing up".

Comment: Dont think its mentioned where her animosity comes from, but the eleint did make a deal with Krul when he created the warrens and this creation of the warrens is what started the loss of power for elder gods and their slow decline. So her hate might stem from that.

Answer (score 1):

Kilmandaros is an Azanthi, but more importantly she is the 'goddess' of the Forkul Assail. The Eleint are a power to match the Azanthi (I think there was an Azanthi-Eleint war) and another power her followers could believe in.

You must understand that in the Malazan-verse gods are simply ascendants with believers, therefore Kilmandaros' power (and every other gods') is tied to how many or how strongly mortals believe in her.  If there is a contesting "god" (an Elient goddess competing) then a pretender is 'cramping her turf'. Additionally, the Krul-Eleint warrens allow others (namely ascendant mortals) to continue the encroachment on her territory.

Comment: Kilmandaros is the mother of the Fokrul Assail NOT their Goddess, the Forkrul Assail killed their god

Comment: Mother... creator... goddess... it is all the same. Being the Azanthi that created them, but not the God worshipped and Ascended by them (then killed), doesn't make her less their goddess.

Answer (score 0):

I think we'll learn more about why she is so angry in the next few Kharkanas books. She seems to have a personal connection to Shadow (why would she agree to drive out the pretenders with Rake?). I know it's not much of an answer, but it's something that hasn't quite been revealed yet.